# NodeJS [Errno 13] Permission denied - Azure DevOps pipleline AWS Lambda deployment

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am setting up the Azure pipeline for NodeJS Serverless to AWS Lambda deployment using this [AWS Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app2container/latest/UserGuide/a2c-integrations-azure-devops.html). During the deployment, getting an error with "[Errno 13] Permission denied":

[image]

When I check the log file, the error message is:

```
2024-03-28T10:11:10.4825015Z 
##[debug]Failed collecting file(s) due to error:
[('/run/cloud-init/combined-cloud-config.json', 
'/tmp/tmpze59c06e/cloud-init-logs-2024-03-28/run/cloud-init/combined-cloud-config.json', 
"[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/run/cloud-init/combined-cloud-config.json'"),
 ('/run/cloud-init/network-config.json', 
'/tmp/tmpze59c06e/cloud-init-logs-2024-03-28/run/cloud-init/network-config.json', 
"[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/run/cloud-init/network-config.json'")]
```

And Yaml code is here:

```
trigger:
- Branch Name

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: LambdaDeployFunction@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'Credential Name'
    regionName: 'region'
    deploymentMode: 'codeonly'
    functionName: 'function name here'
    codeLocation: 'localfile'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm install -g serverless
    serverless config credentials --provider aws --key DummyKeyHere --secret DummySecretKey
    serverless deploy --stage local --region eu-west-1
    
  displayName: 'Deploy to AWS'
```

Not sure what permission is missing.

Comment: Which step had incurred this error `LambdaDeployFunction@1` or `serverless deploy`? If the issue was with the `sls` command, have you tested to run `serverless deploy --stage local --region eu-west-1` authenticating against the **same** key&secret **outside pipeline**? This is helpful to isolate the cause of the issue. Your are reaching out to `Azure DevOps` subcommunity by adding `azure-devops` & `azure-pipelines` tags; however, as far as I understand, the permission should be restricted by AWS IAM  policies rather than from `Azure DevOps` side.